# How to create 3 dots and bracket excerpt and link to blog articles (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress website I just over from another web developer, there is the following excerpts on the blog articles :   [...]

How can I perhaps add a functionality for these brackets and dots to link to blog articles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code:

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
       global $post;
    return '<a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> [...]</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```